# codeigniter session from a phone - a new IP for every pageload

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have encountered the following problem. I cannot log in to my system using a phone. There is a range of 4 ip addresses' endings when I use the phone and therefore system/libraries/Session.php line 192 the IP match returns FALSE for the whole funciton sess_read() and therefore I cannot log from the phone.

What is weird though is that I was able to log in around 2 weeks ago when I was showing my app to my friends. Everything works fine from my PC. It is solely a problem of that condition that incoming IP must be same as the DB IP.

Has anybody of you encountered this? I use the most latest codeigniter version 2.1.3. I dont want to hardcode anything to the Session.php as it is a core library.

Thanks, Jakub

Answer (score 0):

Set `$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;`

If the phone is changing IPs, then it's out of CI's control.

If you absolutely have to have sess_match_ip enabled, you could alternatively add some logic to the config file to set sess_match_ip to true/false on a case-by-case basis.

```
$config['sess_match_ip'] = has_changing_ips();

function has_changing_ips()
{
    /**
     * Code to return true if normal or
     * return false if phone or other device with changing IPs
     */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have written this function for the app/config/config.php:

```
$config['sess_match_ip'] = match_ip(3);

// $range sets -+ of the last numbers
function match_ip ($range){

   session_start();
   $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $IP_parts = explode(".", $IP);

   if (isset($_SESSION['mi'])){

     //If the last part is the same, match IP
     if ($_SESSION['mi'] == $IP_parts['3']){

        return TRUE; // SAME IP doesn't cause the problem, therefore TRUE
     }
     // If the last ending($_S[mi]) is +- 3, IP is dynamic, therefore FALSE
     if (($IP_parts['3']-$range <= $_SESSION['mi']) && ($_SESSION['mi'] <= $IP_parts['3']+$range)) {

        return FALSE;
    }
    else{

        return TRUE;
    }
   }
   // If session not set, set it.
   else{

    $_SESSION['mi'] = $IP_parts['3'];

   }

}
```

I am aware of the problems with ip6v, but for my purposes, this should work. Regarding to the security - at the end of the day, I am storing something in a not encrypted session. BUT IP address is really easy to fake and therefore even ['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE doesn't matter if somebody was trying to hack your sessions. But I like to have the function on.

If you wanna use this code, do more research on how big $range should be. My phone is ranging +-2. But the actual range may be different. If you find out, please post it here.